# What's the best way to make a circular or spiral gradient with css or SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Firstly I Do NOT want a radial gradient (unless it can help me achieve my goal)

I want a circle. The gradient will go from green to blue. The gradient will go clockwise around the circle (not a radial gradient, better described as a spiral gradient or a clockwise gradient). What's the best way to achieve this?

The only idea so far is to divide the circle into many segments and to apply a linear gradient to each segment but I'm hoping for a better solution.

The solution must be achieved with SVG graphics and / or HTML CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: What you are after is a `conical-gradient`..unfortunately, these do not yet exist. https://css-tricks.com/conical-gradients-css/

Comment: Also, there is a polyfil - http://lea.verou.me/2015/06/conical-gradients-today/

Comment: In the case of SVG, try it with Inkscape. Check this out: http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.mx/2012/01/conical-gradients-in-inkscape.html

Comment: Thanks this gives me all I need to research this :)